# Python LDAP3 subdomains search

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, subdomain, ldap3

I have two domains - `example.com` and `corp.example.com` in a single forest. I want to retrieve users' information such as sAMAccountname, distinguishedName, displayName and department from both domains.

This domains are trusted to each other, therefore I can make searches in all domains from a single DC.

The point is to get users' info from all domains being connected to the one DC.

To connect to the AD I'm using

```py
conn = Connection(server=DC_of_the_example.com, user=example.com\user, password=password, auto_bind=AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, auto_referrals=False)
```

I can successfully retrieve information from the `example.com` using

```py
server_connection.search('DC=example,DC=com', '(&(objectclass=user))', attributes=['sAMAccountname', 'distinguishedName', 'displayName', 'department'])
```

But when I'm trying to get the same information from the `corp.example.com` using

```py
server_connection.search('DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com', '(&(objectclass=user))', attributes=['sAMAccountname', 'distinguishedName', 'displayName', 'department'])
```

I'm getting just the empty list.

Is there a way of retrieving this users' info from both domains without a duplicates or maybe I'm missing something?

P.S. I could've used AD Global Catalog, it works just fine, however, it doesn't provide `department` attribute. Thus, it doesn't fit here.

Comment: I believe you would need to allow to follow referrals for this to work. Regular domain controllers (as opposed to Global Catalogs) do not hold all the user information and will include referrals in response which will tell you where to search for further information. You need to follow those hints to get the information you need.